# Don't understand why Set is not null

Tags: java

I suppose the answer is straightforward but I don't see explanation.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> m = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
Set<String> a = new HashSet<String>();

a.add("a");
a.add("b");
a.add("c");

m.put("set", a); // reference    
a = null; // if I type a.remove("b"); variable m holds only a and c as it should

System.out.println(m.get("set")); // Why this prints [a, b, c] as it should null or empty
```

Comment: you just assigned another reference to the same *variable name*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Variable a points to null and   HashMap key "set" points to set [a, b, c], like Kayaman's answer explains.

Comment: absolutely. First you assign `a` to some object, then you assign `a` to null -- so you "unlink" first assignment and replace it by null assignment. Particular object, that was previously assigned to `a`, stays in the heap as it is. By altering assignment, you do not change object itself.

Comment: I understand now what you meant. I changed where a points to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 1 set and 2 references to the set (`a` and the reference inside the map).

You set one reference to null, but that doesn't mean all the other references would be set to null.

Imagine you're pointing at someone and I'm pointing at the same person. Just because you stop pointing, doesn't mean I'll stop pointing.

Once the reference inside the map is removed, the set is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I makes sense, yes. Many variables can point/reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the local variable to null not the reference inside the Map.

If you want to set both to null you have simple remove the Set from the Map.